# Implementing and using SoundTouch class (Java Android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libraries, soundtouch

I've been trying to use the library SoundTouch in my android app in order to change the tempo of an mp3 file.

I've managed to compile the library following the steps outlined here: http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/README-SoundTouch-Android.html

My question now is how do I import and use the compiled library in my android project in Eclipse?

From following the steps in the link above I've ended up with .so files that I've added into the libs folder of my project. I've also changed the build path to include this new library.

The library is now showing up under "referenced libraries" so I'm guessing I'm some where on the right track?

In my java file I've tried importing the library like this:

```
static
    {
    System.loadLibrary("soundtouch");
    }
```

The program builds and runs fine but I don't think the library is actually being loaded as I can't reference any of soundTouch's methods.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: SoundTouch using wav data. Not mp3.

Answer (score 2):

The JNI file provided with the SoundTouch library is merely a demonstration and does not provide any means of using any of SoundTouch's features in an Android app from Java.